# scraping with nodejs coffeescript and cheerio

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, coffeescript, web-scraping

I have a lot of divs with class `name`, I need to extract text and url from each of them

Using `BeautifulSoup` I have tried:

```
for i in BeautifulSoup(page).find_all('div', {'class': 'name'}):
    print i.text
    print i.find('a').get('href')
```

I am new in nodejs/coffeescript so it's hard to understand how it will work in such way

```
$('div.name').each (i, element) ->
    console.log i
```

doesn't work

Comment: is this a python or javascript question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), you should be able to do this.

```
$ = cheerio.load('you html document goes here')
$('div.name').each (i, element) -> 
    console.log el
```

See [cheerio docs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#each-functionindex-element-)

Comment: ReferenceError: el is not defined

Comment: how to get the 'a.href' for element